# Using JavaScript insertBefore() to insert before a TextNode?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have HTML like the following:

```
<div id="move-me">
    <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
</div>

<div id="new-parent">
    Some plain text.
</div>
```

I'm trying to write JavaScript that will move the entire #move-me div inside the #new-parent div, *above* the text, like so:

```
<div id="new-parent">
    <div id="move-me">
        <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
    </div>
    Some plain text.
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript I have:

```
function moveDiv() {
    var moveable = document.getElementById('move-me');
    var newParent = document.getElementById('new-parent');
    newParent.parentNode.insertBefore(moveable, newParent.firstChild);
}
```

I'm using Firebug to debug, and I can see that `newParent.firstChild` is a TextNode, but I always receive the following error:

```
Node was not found" code: "8
newParent.parentNode.insertBefore(moveable, newParent.firstChild);
```

It seems like `insertBefore` requires an element node and won't work on a text node... is that right?  If so, is there another good method for doing this?

**Note**: I can't modify or clean up the HTML to include paragraph tags or remove white space.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, `insertBefore` will work fine with a text node as the node to be inserted before. The problem is that the node you're trying to insert before is not a child of the node you're inserting into. You need to remove the `.parentNode` bit:

```
newParent.insertBefore(moveable, newParent.firstChild);
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you.  Your explanation helps a lot; I've mixed that up on appendChild, too, I think.

Comment: I see - insertBefore must be called on the container/parent node which contains the node I want to insert before.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the ".parentNode" from your insert statement. A text node is still a node and can be referenced like every other node.