# JavaScript the new child is null error when manipulating dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a js function that I want to use to manipulate the dom. For readability sake, let's say I have Element A that I want to insert before Element B. Element A has `display` set to `none` via an inline style. I change the `display` property via the js and attempt the insert, however I get an error "Failed to Execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'. The new child element is null."

As a sanity check, I have two alerts that check if the elements exist in the dom and they both do. Can someone explain how this can be possible and show me how to accomplish this task.

```
document.getElementById('Parent_of_Element_A').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('Parent_of_Element_B').style.display = 'block';
if (document.getElementById('Element_B'))
    alert('Found Reference Element');
if (document.getElementById('A'))
    alert('Found Element to be added');
document.body.insertBefore('A', 'B');
```

Comment: Please show your HTML. Also, `null` is not a valid value for the `visibility` property.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the argument to `insertBefore` is `null` rather than a valid DOM element. The code you posted doesn't have any `insertBefore` calls, please update it with the code that's getting the error.

Comment: This line appears to be the problem: `document.body.insertBefore('A', 'B');` - Rather than passing in the ID of the elements you're talking about, you should pass in a reference to the elements themselves. I.e - `document.body.insertBefore( document.getElementById('idOfA'), document.getElementById('idOfB') );` where idOfA and idOfB are replaced with the actual ids of these elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) takes two DOM elements as properties, *not* strings.  Assuming you want to insert an element with id `a` before element with id `b`, you would do this:

```
 document.getElementById("B").parentNode.insertBefore(document.getElementById("A"), document.getElementById("B"));
```

Comment: I should apologize to @enhzflep for basically answering the question with the exact information he added in a comment, although I started my answer before he posted his comment. :)

Comment: This at least changed the error message. Now I get "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node. "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352871/using-javascript-insertbefore-to-insert-before-a-textnode

Comment: "B" has to have the same parent as "A", or you have to create a new element to insert before "A".

Comment: I used the .firstChild property of the element to achieve what I needed. Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @scott.korin - nah mate. Nothing to worry about. :) (I appreciate the gesture though)

Comment: @scott.korin—no, it doesn't. This answer is backward, `insertBefore(a, b)` will insert `a` before `b`, not the other way around. See [*W3C DOM Core 3:insertBefore*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727).

Comment: Blah, I always get that one backwards.  Thanks, @RobG.