# Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to insert a comment node before the particular node (`<name>`) in my xml. Here is the method for it:

```
function test(xmlResponse)
{
    var parser = new DOMParser(), xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlResponse,"text/xml");

    var comentDocument = document.createComment("My personal comments");

    console.log(xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("street name")[0])
    xmlDoc.insertBefore( comentDocument ,  xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("street name")[0]);

    return xmlDoc
}
```

and when I call:

```
test("<address><street><name>Street name</name></street></address>")
```

I get:

```
<name>Street name</name>
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at Error (native)
    at generateTheComment (<anonymous>:12:9)
    at <anonymous>:2:1
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

As you can see the `<name>Street name</name>` is getting printed correctly; as I want to append the `comentDocument` to its parent `<street>`.

Not sure where I'm making mistake here.

I'm expecting the code to return back:

```
<address>
   <street>
     <!-- My personal comments -->
     <name>Street name
     </name>
   </street>
</address>
```

Comment: Well, it seems like you don't want to insert that comment in the `xmlDoc`, but in that `<street>` node.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352871/using-javascript-insertbefore-to-insert-before-a-textnode

Answer (score 5):

```
xmlDoc.insertBefore( comentDocument ,  xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("street name")[0]);
```

This tries to insert directly from the document. You need to get to the *direct parent* of the element you want to insert your comment before:

```
var name = xmlDoc.querySelector("street name");
name.parentNode.insertBefore(comentDocument, name);
```